# How i can get JSON list without attributes ("count": 3, "next": null, "previous": null, "results":)

Tags: python, json

I have JSON like this:

```
{"count":3,"next":null,"previous":null,"results":[{"name":"Max","slug":"DrMax","directions":["Surgery","Stomach"],"description":"Surgery","work_experience":"2","birt_date":"2018-12-04"},{"name":"Ban","slug":"0","directions":["X-Ray"],"description":"Xray","work_experience":"6","birt_date":"2022-11-02"},{"name":"qwe","slug":"qwe","directions":["Surgery","X-Ray","Stomach"],"description":"Xray","work_experience":"6","birt_date":"2022-11-14"}]}
```

And I want to get JSON like this:

```
[{"name":"Max","slug":"DrMax","directions":["Surgery","Stomach"],"description":"Surgery","work_experience":"2","birt_date":"2018-12-04"},{"name":"Ban","slug":"0","directions":["X-Ray"],"description":"Xray","work_experience":"6","birt_date":"2022-11-02"},{"name":"qwe","slug":"qwe","directions":["Surgery","X-Ray","Stomach"],"description":"Xray","work_experience":"6","birt_date":"2022-11-14"}]
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

If you have whole json as a dictionary like this:

```
response_json = {"count":3,"next":null,"previous":null,"results":[{"name":"Max","slug":"DrMax","directions":["Surgery","Stomach"],"description":"Surgery","work_experience":"2","birt_date":"2018-12-04"},{"name":"Ban","slug":"0","directions":["X-Ray"],"description":"Xray","work_experience":"6","birt_date":"2022-11-02"},{"name":"qwe","slug":"qwe","directions":["Surgery","X-Ray","Stomach"],"description":"Xray","work_experience":"6","birt_date":"2022-11-14"}]}
```

All you need is just get the value by the needed key:

```
results = response_json.get("results")
```